# How can I display the rank of a user?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm building a small rank system that will eventually allow certain users to access certain portions of my website.. I'm connecting to my database and selecting the correct table/column that contains that data I'm looking for, but for some reason it is empty?

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
include "dbconf.php"; 
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    //Trying to set PDO error mode to exception I guess?
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //No Need to say if we connected successfully. // echo "Connected Successfully!";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT rank FROM members"); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $userrank;
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection to database has failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
function ShowRank() {
    echo 'Rank: ' . $userrank;
}
```

So when this code executes I don't get any errors of any kind. But what I do get is an empty `$userrank`. When I try to call it on another page it returns:

`Rank:` but nothing else.

Comment: 1. *Undefined* `$userrank` 2. Scope issue: `$userrank` is not available in the scope of your function.

Comment: 3. `ShowRank()` is never called

Comment: *I don't get any errors of any kind*, you don't unless you turn on error reporting. Add these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your PHP scripts.

Comment: ...and check your servers error log

Comment: you never assign anything to $userrank, you also don't filter your query so it will pull back all ranks for all users.

Comment: Hi Magnus, ShowRank(); is actually called on the page I'm displaying the content on. This is merely the php page that contains the function.

Comment: @JeffUK How would I filter it properly to display the logged in users rank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
include "dbconf.php"; 
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    //Trying to set PDO error mode to exception I guess?
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //No Need to say if we connected successfully. // echo "Connected Successfully!";
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT rank FROM members");
    $userrank = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection to database has failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
function ShowRank($user) {
    echo 'Rank: ' . $user[1]->rank;
}
ShowRank($userrank);
```